# "Create Another XXX" button not working in ActiveScaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

**Update#1** Surprisingly if in Firebug, I change the generated <input> HTML to <a>, it works as expected. But to make this workaround permanent, I will have to change ActiveScaffold's code.

**Update#2** For now I have changed the code of ActiveScaffold. This solves my problem. But the questions is still not answered.

I have a model ListingMovie:

```
class ListingMovie
  has_many :movie_shows, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :movie
  ...
  ...
end
```

and MovieShow:

```
class MovieShow
  belongs_to :listing_movie

  validates_presence_of :start_time, :end_time
end
```

I have Manage::ListingMoviesController:

```
class Manage::ListingMoviesController < Manage::BaseController
  helper Mange::MovieShowsHelper

  active_scaffold :listing_movie do |config|

    config.columns = [:movie, :listing, :start_date, :end_date, :movie_shows]
    config.columns[:listing].form_ui = :select
    config.columns[:movie].form_ui = :select
  end

  protected

  def self.active_scaffold_controller_for(klass)
    return Manage::MoviesController if klass == Movie
    return Mange::MovieShowsController if klass == MovieShow
  end
end
```

and Manage::MovieShowsController

```
class Manage::MovieShowsController < Manage::BaseController
  active_scaffold :movie_show do |config|
    config.subform.columns = [:start_time, :end_time]
  end
end
```

When I try to create/update a ListingMovie, I am shown a form that has a "Create Another Movie Show" the end. Earlier when I clicked it, it made an Ajax request and added two new fields at the bottom of the form that let me specify start_time and end_time for associated MovieShow. Now When I click on it, no request is made to the server. And hence new fields are not added to the form.

Following is the HTML of the button:

```
<input data-remote="true" href="/manage/listing_movies/edit_associated?association=movie_shows" id="as_manage__listing_movies--movie_shows-subform-create-another" style="" type="button" value="Create Another Movie show">
```

I am unable to debug this as I can see any errors. Clicking the button simply does nothing.

One thing to notice is that if I put some erroneous data in the form and then try to "Create/Update" a ListingMovie, the form is rendered again with a "new" form fields to specify start_time and end_time.

I am using Rails 3.0.1 and ActiveScaffold 3.0.6
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use href in a input tag.
Define an onclick event for the button or use it inside an ancor tag

```
<a href="/manage/listing_movies/edit_associated?association=movie_shows">
<input data-remote="true" id="as_manage__listing_movies--movie_shows-subform-create-another" style="" type="button" value="Create Another Movie show">
</a>
```

this may be helpful to you

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/button.html

Comment: Instead of putting an `input` tag inside of `anchor` tags, I am using only `anchor` tags.